# How can I configure the threshold when my fan sets in (laptop)

Tags: linux, temperature, fan

I'm using a sony vaio pro 13 with linux, but unfortunately the fan is already at maximum at only 50 degrees Celsius.

How can I change the threshold it sets in?

Distro is arch btw.

Comment: What disro of Linux is this?

Comment: The distro I use is Arch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need should be covered in the Arch Linux wiki article titled [Fan speed control](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fan_speed_control).

*excerpt*

> Once sensors is properly configured, run `pwmconfig` to test and configure speed control. Follow the instructions in `pwmconfig` to set up basic speeds. The default configuration options should create a new file, `/etc/fancontrol`.

You can augment the fan parameters in that config file. For example:

```
INTERVAL=10
DEVPATH=hwmon0=devices/platform/coretemp.0 hwmon2=devices/platform/w83627ehf.656
DEVNAME=hwmon0=coretemp hwmon2=w83627dhg
FCTEMPS=hwmon0/device/pwm1=hwmon0/device/temp1_input
FCFANS= hwmon0/device/pwm1=hwmon0/device/fan1_input
MINTEMP=hwmon0/device/pwm1=20
MAXTEMP=hwmon0/device/pwm1=55
MINSTART=hwmon0/device/pwm1=150
MINSTOP=hwmon0/device/pwm1=105
```

*breakdown*

> - `MINTEMP`: The temperature (°C) at which to SHUT OFF the CPU fan. Efficient CPUs often will not need a fan while idling. Be sure to set
>     this to a temperature that you know is safe. Setting this to 0 is not
>     recommended and may ruin your hardware!
> - `MAXTEMP`: The temperature (°C) at which to spin the fan at its MAXIMUM speed. This should be probably be set to perhaps 10 or 20
>     degrees (°C) below your CPU's critical/shutdown temperature. Setting
>     it closer to MINTEMP will result in higher fan speeds overall.
> - `MINSTOP`: The PWM value at which your fan stops spinning. Each fan is a little different. Power tweakers can `echo` different values
>     (between 0 and 255) to `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/pwm1` and then
>     watch the CPU fan. When the CPU fan stops, use this value.
> - `MINSTART`: The PWM value at which your fan starts to spin again. This is often a higher value than MINSTOP as more voltage is required
>     to overcome inertia.